# SOAP Authentication of Username Password Token Failed

Tags: php, soap

I have some problem with SOAP. I have some functionality in my system, that check if person is a debtor. It worked fine for a long time, but suddenly it stopped.
Now when i try to call out this function i get this error:

`Error 500
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Authentication of Username Password Token Failed`

This is my controller:

```
public function actionQuery($client, $loan)
{
    $client = Client::model()->findByPk($client);
    $loan = Loan::model()->findByPk($loan);

    list($success, $exists, $debtorsInfoPersonId) = $client->getDebtorInfo($loan->add);

    if ($success) {
        Report::set(Report::SUCCESS, Yii::t('app', 'Data received'));
    }

    if ($exists) {
        Report::set(Report::NOTICE, Yii::t('app', 'Debtor exists'));
    } else {
        Report::set(Report::NOTICE, Yii::t('app', 'Debtor not exists'));
    }

    $url = Yii::app()->request->getParam('returnUrl', null);
    $this->redirect($url != null ? base64_decode($url) : ['view', 'id' => $model->debtorPerson->getPrimaryKey()]);
}
```

And this is component with soap.

```
private function generateWSSecurity($user, $password)
{
    // Creating date using yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ format
    $tm_created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $tm_expires = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', gmdate('U') + 180);

    // Generating, packing and encoding a random number
    $simple_nonce = mt_rand();
    $encoded_nonce = base64_encode(pack('H*', $simple_nonce));

    // Compiling WSS string
    $passdigest = base64_encode(pack('H*',
        sha1(pack('H*', $simple_nonce) . pack('a*', $tm_created) . pack('a*', $password))));

    // Initializing namespaces
    $ns_wsse = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
    $ns_wsu = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';
    $password_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest';
            //$password_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf';
    $encoding_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary';
            //$encoding_type = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf';

    // Creating WSS identification header using SimpleXML
    $root = new \SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');

    $security = $root->addChild('wsse:Security', null, $ns_wsse);

    $timestamp = $security->addChild('wsu:Timestamp', null, $ns_wsu);
    $timestamp->addAttribute('wsu:Id', 'Timestamp-28');
    $timestamp->addChild('wsu:Created', $tm_created, $ns_wsu);
    $timestamp->addChild('wsu:Expires', $tm_expires, $ns_wsu);

    $usernameToken = $security->addChild('wsse:UsernameToken', null, $ns_wsse);
    $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Username', $user, $ns_wsse);

    $password = $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Password', $passdigest, $ns_wsse);
    $password->addAttribute('Type', $password_type);

    $nonce = $usernameToken->addChild('wsse:Nonce', $encoded_nonce, $ns_wsse);
    $nonce->addAttribute('EncodingType', $encoding_type);

    $usernameToken->addChild('wsu:Created', $tm_created, $ns_wsu);

    // Recovering XML value from that object
    $root->registerXPathNamespace('wsse', $ns_wsse);
    $full = $root->xpath('/root/wsse:Security');
    $auth = $full[0]->asXML();

    return $auth;
}
```

When i use `die("error")` to checko where is the problem, everything works fine till `return $auth;`. Error shows after this return. Any clue what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Test you Webservice with https://www.soapui.org/
Download it.
Verify if you login with software.